# Variadic template initilizer_list trick

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, c++17

I've wrote for_each_tuple with C++17 on visual studio 2017 RC and I am horrified about that implementation.

Check out:

```
template<class fun_t, class tuple_t>
constexpr auto for_each_tuple(fun_t& fun, tuple_t&& tuple) {

    std::apply([&](auto&&... args) {
        auto l = { (fun(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)), 0)... };
    }, std::forward<tuple_t>(tuple));
}

int main() {
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(
        1, 2, 3, 4
    );
    for_each_tuple([](auto& arg) { ++arg; }, tup);
    for_each_tuple([](auto& arg) {std::cout << arg; }, tup);

}
```

output:
2345

I have serious questions about this part:

```
auto l = { (fun(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)), 0)... };
```

Is that just compiler trick or fully standard correct way?

And how exactly function call parsed into std::initilizer_list ?

How make that function better on your opinion?

Comment: C++17 should allow you to fold the expression directly without having to use the 0 value initializer list trick.

Comment: This code is illegal: you're passing an rvalue and binding it to a non-const lvalue reference. MSVC allows this as an extension (with a level 4 warning), but it is illegal nonetheless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++17, this:

```
auto l = { (fun(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)), 0)... };
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
(fun(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)), ...);
```

The list trick is a perfectly legal (from the point of view of the standard) C++11/C++14 workaround while waiting for fold expressions.
The basic idea is to create a list (or an array) to be discarded immediately after. That container is filled with zeros, because of how the comma operator works. Finally, the unfolding of the parameter pack simply forces the invokation of the given function for each parameter.
In other terms, you can imagine it as it follows:

```
auto l = { (fun(std::forward<decltype(arg0)>(arg0)), 0), (fun(std::forward<decltype(arg1)>(arg1)), 0), (fun(std::forward<decltype(arg2)>(arg2)), 0), and so on... };
```